# How to make a checkmark UIButton in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to make a checkmark UIButton in iOS like the second icon in the enclosed image.

Does Apple provide this checkmark button in the SDK ?

Any suggestion to make a checkmark UIButton ?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

No, there isn't a built-in checkmark button type. You'll have to use `UIButtonTypeCustom` and provide your own images for the different control states by calling `setBackgroundImage:forControlState:`. You could use the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) tool to get at the original images, but doing so *may* lead to a rejection.

Comment: I've extracted yellow UIActionSheet button image from Voice Memos app. No rejection, too.